# Bash Script in Ubuntu to download pics and store them locally

Tags: scripts, wget

How can I make a bash script in Ubuntu that gets pictures consecutively from a site and stores them locally?

I need to download the images from  where `XX` is a number between 01-12.

EDIT1: So I have found 2 ways to save them locally, thanks guys!

Comment: Could you provide more details? are the URL "consecutive"?

Comment: why not just use `wget`?   (if its a school assignment, sorry I won't help except provide clues as to why something doesn't work)

Comment: Read about [`for` loops](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/classic_for), [`while` loops](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/while_loop) and [Bash Brace Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) and you'll gain the knowledge to solve your assignment.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
wget https://www.pbei.be/scripting/{01..12}.jpg
```

That will download all images from `01.jpg` to `12.jpg` and save them in the current directory.

Answer (score 5):

You can use curl's expansion patterns:

```
curl 'https://www.pbei.be/scripting/[01-12].jpg' -o 'image#1.jpg'
```

This creates 12 images named `image01.jpg` .. `image12.jpg`

Comment: But I want to store them using a for or while loop. Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: @Felix, That is possible too. Try  `for a in ...; do ... done` see the details in a bash tutorial or a bash man page